# Scopes added to Gmail API project aren't reflected in OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I've added *all scopes available* to my Gmail API project via the Google Developer Console. It's registered as an **Internal** application type, so none of the scopes are *sensitive*.

I've saved and re-saved these settings, regenerated OAuth client IDs and updated them to be used in my flow.

However, when I get to the Google OAuth consent screen, the scopes are listed as:

> **This will allow [App Name] to:**
>
> View your email messages and settings

None of the other scopes I have selected are listed.

Here are some screenshots which might help:

**OAuth consent screen:**

[image]

**OAuth settings (public/internal) - Google API Console**

[image]

**Scopes - Google API Console**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this one out eventually.

The OAuth settings screen I have in my question only provides for scope permissions to be requested. In order to actually access a specific scope, you must add it in the consent settings screen, and pass it to the API as part of the OAuth flow.

The solution was to add the requisite scopes to my code as well.